# Javascript MVC Design Feedback

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

i would like to share my design of mvc via js.

What do you think about it?
I tried to not use any mvc framework but i want to get clear structure and a decoupled organisation.

Next step for me is evaluating something like require.js to get rid of the ordering within the index file

The code:
http://nopaste.info/2547415f71_nl.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about evaluating the design of a program. [codereview.se] might be a better fit, provided you post your code in the question itself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, which belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, if at all. At least make sure to include your code in your post, not on some other site.

Comment: Did not know codereview.stackechange.com, thank you. Made a post there

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30358/javascript-mvc-design-feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should bind the click events in the view. Controller can be made "pure logic, no DOM".
Also, in the view -

Instead of

```
var uiComponents = {
        contactList:  "#contactList"
    };
```

you could do -

```
var uiComponents = {
        contactList:  $("#contactList")
    };
```

which will traverse the DOM only once and cache the element for you which you could use elsewhere.
The Model looks clean (no coupling with View or Controller).

Comment: contactList:  $("#contactList") cannot be found at this moment. Thats why it is within the __addContact fucntion